# Odd numbers recursively? code currently finds even nums

Tags: algorithm, recursion

Just wondering if there is a line change I can make in order to find odds instead of evens? Here's what I got:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include "stdafx.h"

void numOdd(int x, int y)
{
    std::cout << x << " ";
    if (x < y)
    {
    numOdd(x + 2, y);

    }
}

int main()
{
    int x = 0;
    int y = 0;
    std::cout << "Up to what num to find odd nums? " << std::endl;
    std::cin >> y;
    numOdd(x, y);
    _getch();
}
```

Comment: When you get to a resolution, please remember to up-vote useful things and accept your favourite answer (even if you have to write it yourself), so Stack Overflow can properly archive the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Initialize x to 1 instead of 0.

Aso, be advised that recursion is not a great fit for this problem; a simple loop would be more appropriate.

Comment: If this answer your question, please accept the answer.

Comment: Thanks! It was an exercise in recursion.